# Create Image from container keeping configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created a container via compose. This container has already port binded and path for the volume.

I am wondering if it is possible create an image from this container keeping the configuration such binded port, volume path and variable?

So I do docker run <NEW_IMAGE> and everything is already setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings like volumes mounts and published ports are never included as part of an image and there's no way to create an image that contains them.  You will always need to include `-v` and `-p` options in a `docker run` command if you're launching a container that way.

An easier approach may be to simply publish your `docker-compose.yml` file as the preferred way to run your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I am using already the compose.